# Why doesn't my function to calculate monthly car payments work?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a small web app that users can enter their ideal car price and find out how much (on average) their monthly payment will be.

Half of the function works and am able to get the *topHalf* variable with the calculation but not the rest of the equation.

**Formula Used**

http://teachertech.rice.edu/Participants/bchristo/lessons/carpaymt.html

**HTML USED**

```
<input type="input" placeholder="carPrice" id="rPrice">
    <input type="input" placeholder="deposit" id="deposit">
    <input type="input" placeholder="interest rate" id="iRate">
    <input type="input" placeholder="loan term" id="tMonth">
    <a onclick="findPayment()">Calculate</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT USED**

```
function findPayment() {

/* Add User's unique input fields here */

var regPrice = document.getElementById("rPrice").value;
deposit = document.getElementById("deposit").value;
rate = document.getElementById("iRate").value;
mth = document.getElementById("tMonth").value;

/* Find updated price including user's deposit */

uptPrice = regPrice - deposit;

/* Formula to Calculate Here */

topHalf = uptPrice * ( rate / mth );
bottomHalf = 1 - Math.pow( 1 + rate / 12, -mth)
custom = topHalf / bottomHalf;

/* Send monthly payment to console so I can check */

console.log(custom);

};
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What is not working? do you get an error? or  the wrong result?

Comment: I think i just fixed it :) with the help of everyone here of course!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to [`parseInt`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwjV3aiDyOvIAhWJvBoKHfgmDXI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FparseInt&usg=AFQjCNH1Q7PXyL6tFQWn0vEWgI0_RUQVFg) or [`parseFloat`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCQQFjABahUKEwiJl9KEyOvIAhWE1RoKHfyEBUk&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FparseFloat&usg=AFQjCNFGjOkpZ1cWnWNYHgjw0eQjZTiL0g) the values of the actual inputs to manipulate them as numbers.

Currently it should be display NaN or something of that sort, NaN stands for *Not a Number*, it shows that because you are trying to use mathematical operators on strings.

Comment: Hmm I see. Do you know why the `topHalf = uptPrice * ( rate / mth );` part still calculates?

Comment: So my question is the function works without parseInt.....is it supposed to or is the answer its giving wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You also have one error on your code above, at least the way you have it above: Math.Pow should be Math.pow.

Comment: You should also avoid creating global variables - declare your variables with the var keyword to create local ones.

Comment: I thought if i make the first variable with `var regPrice` the ones below it would also be local to the function? Am i wrong here?

Comment: No that won't work because the first variable's line is terminated by the semicolon at the end.  You can declare all your variables with a single var keyword using commas, i.e. var regPrice, deposit, rate, ... and so on.  Avoid global variables so that you do not pollute the global namespace - best practice is to keep your variables local.

Comment: Oh! Thank you for that :) Yes I will avoid them.